# Azure Search Indexer fails - “Indexing was stopped because the free skillset execution quota has been reached.”

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Today I noticed a problem with my Azure Search Indexer – “Indexing was stopped because the free skillset execution quota has been reached.”.
[Indexer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3wlw.png)

It used to work fine ( at least since last November to 8th February when I last found it to be healthy). Is there anything changed in this area ( since I had always used the free skillset execution and got 232637 documents indexed without any failures with this error previously)? I thought if the quota exceeded, the remaining documents will be indexed in the next run.

[Indexer when it was working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p0Rx.png)

While I have now provisioned a dedicated Cognitive Service for a new index to pull data again, just trying to see if anything can be done about this index and want to understand why there’s this change in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting on February 1 2019, free skillset execution has a cap of 20 documents a day. To unblock current execution, you would have to attach a Cognitive Services Resource. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services